# How to update a listView from other thread on JavaFX?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, thread-safety

Hi I'm on a particular problem. Let me explain:
I'm working with JavaFX and controlling some Nodes from other class (*let's call it: **class A** and to the javaFX controller class: **class B***).
Inside the group of nodes I'm using a listView, so from class B I'm adding to a listModel (the listModel of the listView). **The problem consist when I add to that listModel**, the JavaFX application **gets freeze**. Java throws an expection like this:

> Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = pool-2-thread-1

I'm running that code(the one where I add elements to the listModel) on a **Task** but before that I'm execute that "Task" on a ExecutorService like this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); // pool of one thread
executorService.execute(task); // start the task
executorService.shutdown();
```

The executorService is called from a method inside **class B** (JavaFX controller).
The application unfreeze some seconds after the listModel has already added the elements.

Of course I used:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> action())
```

to perform JavaFX updates. When I perform the addition of elements in the listModel inside a *Platform.runLater()*  the application doesn't gets freeze but the listModel does not add anything because of some manner the variable that the listModel.add( element ) receive does not exist in JavaFX thread, at least I suppose that.

here is a sample:

```
for (RemoteXBeeDevice remote : network.getDevices()) {

    if (remote != null) {
        if (!remote.getNodeID().endsWith("SENSOR")) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> listModel.add(remote)));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After some changes the listModel already add the elements but the application still gets freeze.

Comment: Have you verified that it isn't actually adding or is it just not updating visually?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that, actually is adding (after some changes, is doing it), but still gets freeze(after unfreeze, the listview updates visually).

Comment: A freeze suggests an infinite loop.  Have you added any listeners to the ListView’s item list, or to any other ListView properties?

Comment: @VGR yes I have, on my JFXcontroller class I have a
    listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()

Comment: Approximately how many times does `Platform.runLater()` get called in that loop?

Comment: @James_D on the Task process approximately 7 times. inside the for loop on the sample 2 times.

Comment: There are basically two different ways you can make the UI freeze: one is by running a blocking or long-running process on the FX Application thread, and the other is by submitting more `Runnable`s to `Platform.runLater()` than the FX Application Thread can reasonably handle. It doesn't sound like you are doing the latter, so you must somehow be blocking the FX Application Thread. I don't think the issue is in the code you posted; see if you can create a [MCVE] (just use mock-up for the processes that take a long time in the real application and create a UI with just the list).

Comment: @James_D Thank you! I notice something, on the question I was talking about that the listModel reveived an "empty" variables. Well that situation is present doing this: 

`Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        for (RemoteXBeeDevice remote : network.getDevices()) {

                            if (remote != null) {
                                if (!remote.getNodeID().endsWith("SENSOR")) {
                                    listModel.add(remote);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });`

Comment: @James_D The listView gets populated whithout problem with the new items but when I want to reference that items, Java throws me an exception
`Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at demos.utilities.XBeeNode$1.run(XBeeNode.java:73)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`  And I don't have a reference to that items, I can't control them because they are "empty". But at some manner the name of the item is displayed on the listView...